# How to add API to javascript file inside github-pages repository

Tags: javascript, github, github-actions, repository

I used the GitHub page to build a web-based calculator for my lab, and it comes with a small support tool named "[addchemicals](https://github.com/ylklab/ylklab.github.io/tree/main/functions/addchemicals)" so users can add the chemical data they want. [(Here's the link](https://github.com/ylklab/ylklab.github.io))

The problem is that the tool needs API Key to push chemicals data to the GitHub repository, which the calculator fetches data and do its work, and for some obvious reason, GitHub do not allow users storing their API inside a public repository.

After some research, I found out someone said that I could use action secrets to make an environment variable for my app, and try some workflow examples but I still don't know how to combine the environment variable with a JavaScript file.

Comment: What do you mean with API? API stands for application programming interface. Do you mean an API key, a library? Do you ask how to access an API?

Comment: @jabaa It's API key.
I used `const API_token = 'xxxxxxxx'` in my test server(vs code live server), but I need to publish it to github pages and github do not allow me to store my API Key in repository.

Comment: That usually means that the service shouldn't be accessed from the frontend, but from your backend.